# Accessing std::vector created in class constructor

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a class with a std::vector as element. I initialize and populate the vector in the constructor. However when I try to access the vector using `this->` form a method in the class, I get an empty vector.

The code looks pretty much like the following:

```
myclass::myclass() {       
    std::vector<double> pars(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    pars.at(i) = some_value;
    }
}

double myclass::method(int i) {
    return this->pars.at(i); 
}
```

I can see the elements into the vector within the constructor. However, `myclass::method(int i)` always returns 0 and the array `this->pars` has size 0. Any suggestion?

I have declared `pars` in a separate header file as:

```
class myclass {
    private:
    std::vector<double> pars;
    ...
}
```

Comment: `pars` in your code snippet is a local variable to your constructor; it sounds like you also have a class member called `pars` (these are two different variables despite having the same name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Main issue

In your constructor:

```
myclass::myclass() {       
    std::vector<double> pars(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    pars.at(i) = some_value;
    }
}
```

you are declaring a local `pars` object, which is therefore only shared within the constructor block and not the entire class.

I can see other language influences in this, but in C++ class members must be declared in the class declaration/definition itself:

```
class myclass {
private:
    std::vector<double> pars;
public:
    ...
};
```

Then in your constructor you can use an *initializer list* to pass arguments to the member constructor:

```
myclass::myclass() : pars (1000) { ... }
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### Some tips

Please notice that in C++ you don't need to prefix member variable access with `this->`.

And finally, you can use `std::vector`'s constructor to generate `n` copies of a certain element:

```
myclass::myclass() : pars (1000, element) { ... }
```

in alternative you can use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) in `<algorithm>` to fill the entire container once it is created:

```
std::fill(pars.begin(), pars.end(), element);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to keep `pars` as a member and initialize it as:

```
class myclass
{
private:
  std::vector<double> pars;
}
```

...

```
pars = std::vector<double>(1000,some_value);
```

Comment: I have a separate header file in which I declare pars as a private member. Would that be the same?

Comment: @user3278488, ok then, you just need pars = std::vector<double>(1000,some_value);

Answer (score 0):

You will want to change `pars` to a member variable as below.

```
class myclass {
public:
    myclass();
    double method(int i);

private:
    std::vector<double> m_pars;
    double myclass::method(int i);
};

double myclass::method(int i) {
    return this->m_pars.at(i); 
}
```

Consider using the constructor of `std::vector` or `std::fill` instead of looping over the values.